# delete unique rows from table having minimum value using joins

Tags: oracle

```
select a.rowid,a.ta_transaction_at_k,a.ta_approvalid_k 
from OF_TATRANSACTIONAPPROVALS a,OF_ATAVAILMENTTICKETS b 
where a.TA_TRANSACTION_AT_K=b.at_transaction_k
  and a.TA_APPROVALROLE_RO = 98
  and a.TA_APPROVALTYPE = 'TA' 
  and b.AT_GROUP_ID=402
```

I have this query which gives result in below format. How can I delete records from it

```
331789  3
331789  4
331789  5
331787  3
331787  4
331787  5
```

I want to delete ids with minimum values

Comment: please help in this i want to remove ids which has min value corresponding to it.

Comment: Could you please specify the expected output?

Comment: Do you want to delete from table OF_TATRANSACTIONAPPROVALS or from table OF_ATAVAILMENTTICKETS?

Answer (score 0):

got the issue resolved using row ids.

delete from OF_TATRANSACTIONAPPROVALS where rowid in(
select rowsid from(
select a.rowid rowsid,a.ta_transaction_at_k trns,a.ta_approvalid_k,row_number() over (partition by TA_TRANSACTION_AT_K order by TA_TRANSACTION_AT_K,ta_approvalid_k) rn 
from OF_TATRANSACTIONAPPROVALS a,OF_ATAVAILMENTTICKETS b where a.TA_TRANSACTION_AT_K=b.at_transaction_k
and a.TA_APPROVALROLE_RO = 98 and a.TA_APPROVALTYPE = 'TA' and b.AT_GROUP_ID=402) where rn=1)